# Insert term and child term from frontend

Tags: php, terms

I have this taxonomy: "free", and I want to insert new term (ex: Season) and then insert a child to this term (ex: episode) in the same form.
Taxonomy "free"
Add new term: ex: Season, and then add ex: Episode term with Season parent.
This is my code:

```
<?php

// Check to see if correct form is being submitted, if so continue to process
if( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) &&  $_POST['action'] == "new_term") {

    // Check to see if input field for new term is set 
    if (isset ($_POST['term'])) {

        // If set, stores user input in variable
        $new_term =  $_POST['term'];
        $new_description =  $_POST['description'];

wp_insert_term(
  '' . $new_term . '', // the term 
  'free', // the taxonomy
  array(
    'description'=> '' . $new_description . '',
    'slug' => '' . $new_term .''

  )
);

    } else { 

        // Else throw an error message
        echo 'Please enter a taxonomy name!';     

    }

}

?>

<form id="insert_term" name="insert_term" method="post" action=""> 

    <input type="text" value="" name="term" id="term" /> 
    <input type="text" value="" name="description" id="description" /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Add Club" id="submit" name="submit" />
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="new_term" />

</form>
```